# Kafka Tool / Offset Explorer - Where to view Debug Logging?

Tags: apache-kafka

In the Kafka Tool / Offset Explorer application, under Settings>General, there is a setting to enable debug logging.

[image]

Where can we view the debug logs in Kafka Tool / Offset Explorer after enabling debug logging?

Comment: I assume it outputs some log data to a directory?

Comment: Has anyone an idea where this is under Windows? Haven't found it yet...

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht I did a search on Windows for `error.log` as mentioned by Ahmed below on his Mac, but didn't find anything related to Offset Explorer/Kafka Tool. Let me know if you find it..

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the location of the log file on MacOS, it is in this path `/Applications/Offset Explorer 2.app/Contents/Resources/app` then you will find a file named `error.log`

P.S. it is a big file, so use the tail command with it, or delete it and try to reproduce the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows the debug log (error.log) can be found in the same directory as the executable. If you don't find it there, then run the executable as admin.